# Primefaces datatable select row not working in viewscope

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, view-scope, session-scope

In my application I am using `ViewScoped` Bean and it does not show selected row when a row is selected in primefaces datatable. But if I changed the Bean to a `SessionScoped` Bean then it shows the selected row perfectly.

I read some forum posts and I found that using `ViewaccessScoped` bean will solve the issue. Can someone help me in this issue? My jsf version is 2.2.

Comment: Which package did you import the view scope annotation from? There are two and the right one to use depends on who's managing the bean, JSF or CDI.

Comment: I used ViewAccessedScoped Bean in place of ViewScoped and getting following errors,org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped

Comment: @BalusC I am using import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped; when using ViewScoped.and When I used import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped; results in null pointer exception and at least doesn't show primefaces datatable.

Comment: That's thus the one from CDI. And who's managing the bean? JSF (via `@ManagedBean`) or CDI (via `@Named`)? By the way, the `@ViewAccessScoped` from CODI has already a JSF 2.2 equivalent, the `@FlowScoped`, so installing CODI for that wasn't been necessary. Just try to fix the problem instead of looking for workarounds.

Comment: @BalusC i am using JSF managedbean

Comment: Then you should be using the `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` annotation from JSF and fix that NPE. What exactly is `null` and causing the NPE?

Comment: @BalusC In my program I am putting selected row in to a cartesian chart and it is causing this NPE. java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.primefaces.component.chart.CartesianChart.getCategories(CartesianChart.java:32)

Comment: @BalusC I tried removing that cartesian loading part and then also datatable returns no values without exceptions.

Comment: @BalusC I must say sorry , Beacuse I am using annotation @Named(value = "xxx"). So I must basically use javax.faces.view.ViewScoped, I will try to identify the error.

Comment: @BalusC I still could not solve. I moved my question to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068101/primefaces-datatable-row-selection-does-not-work-in-viewscope) please help.